# Unable to find getSpanSize() in flutter gridView

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

I am trying to create the bellow UI using `GridView` where every 5th child take full width will contain ads. This is how it will look like

[image]

[image]

Hy i faces this issue regarding spaces? How to remove this extra space??

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce same issue?

Comment: I've made an edit check if work out, else cancel and do update.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of UI I prefer using [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

You can follow this code example

```dart
class TestLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget item(int index) => Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)),
        child: Text("${index}"),
      );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: StaggeredGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: [
            ...List.generate(
              40, // include  items.lenght+1
              (index) => index == 0
                  ? const SizedBox() // ignore the 0th index
                  : index % 5 == 0
                      ? StaggeredGridTile.count(
                          crossAxisCellCount: 2,
                          mainAxisCellCount: 1,
                          child: item(index), // use index-1 while passing data
                        )
                      : StaggeredGridTile.count(
                          crossAxisCellCount: 1,
                          mainAxisCellCount: 1,
                          child: item(index),
                        ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited a question, please feel free to answer my question, how to remove extra spaces around ads?

Comment: By using below space you can able to add extra spaces  crossAxisSpacing: 4
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4